# ArcGIS-JS-API - Custom Content in Popup Template is display nothing (Angular 11)

Tags: javascript, angular, esri, arcgis-js-api

I want to display a hyperlink on the bottom of the popup template in arcgis esri map. I've added the code I've tried, but hyperlink is not displaying in the popup template. Only the fields table is displaying. Could you please have look into this code and let me know if I've missed something.

**.ts file**

```
const popUpTemplate = new PopupTemplate({
  title: "{name}",
  content: [
      {
          type: "fields",
          fieldInfos: [
              {
                  fieldName: "PhysicianName",
                  label: "Physician Name"
              },
              {
                  fieldName: "Practice",
                  label: "Primary Practise",

              },
          ]
      },
    new CustomContent({
      outFields: ["*"],
      creator: (graphic) => {
          const a = document.createElement("a");
          a.href = "https://www.youtube.com/";
          a.target = "_blank";
          a.innerText = graphic.attributes.PhysicianName;
          return a;
      }
  })
  ],
  outFields: ["*"]
});
   
    const myLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    source: physicianData.map((d,i)=>(
      {
          geometry: new Point({
            longitude: d.Longitude,
            latitude: d.Latitude
          }),
          attributes: {
            ObjectID: i,
            name : d.PhysicianName,
            PhysicianName : d.PhysicianName,
            Practice : d.Practice,
            ...d
          }
      }
    )),
    fields: [{
      name: "ObjectID",
      alias: "ObjectID",
      type: "oid"
    }, 
    {
      name: "name",
      alias: "Physician : ",
      type: "string"
    },
    {
      name: "PhysicianName",
      alias: "Physician Name",
      type: "string"
    },
    {
      name: "Practice",
      alias: "Practice",
      type: "string"
    },
   ],
  objectIdField: 'ObjectID',
  geometryType: "point",
  popupTemplate : popUpTemplate,
});
```

**.html file**

```
    <div #mapViewNode></div>
```

Comment: Please create a stackblitz demo so that we can debug, this issue might be because of CSS also. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi @VimalPatel. I found the issue and it's with **graphic.attributes** is null. Can anyone help with why that value is not coming in graphic object?

Comment: without debugging its difficult to answer. requesting you to please create a stackblitz demo to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you need to define the fields of the layer.

If you are working with client side graphics and `FeatureLayer`, you need to set:

- `source`, the collection of graphics (geometry + attributes)
- `objectIdField`, the field that is going to identify the graphics, type `oid` (*)
- `fields`, the name, alias, and type of each field of the graphics attributes

In your case, just by deducing the possible attributes, it should be something like this

```
const dataFeedLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    source: locationData.map((d,i)=>(
        {
            geometry: new Point({
                longitude: d.longitude,
                latitude: d.latitude
            }),
            attributes: {
                ObjectID: i,
                ...d
            }
        }
    )),
    objectIdField: 'ObjectID',
    popupTemplate : popUpTemplate,
    fields: [
        {
            name: "ObjectID",
            alias: "ID",
            type: "oid"
        },
        {
            name: "PhysicianName",
            alias: "Physician Name",
            type: "string"
        },
        {
            name: "PrimarySpecialty",
            alias: "Primary Specialty",
            type: "string"
        },
        {
            name: "url",
            alias: "Url",
            type: "string"
        }
    ]
});
```

> When creating a FeatureLayer from client-side features, this property should be set in the constructor along with the source property. The objectId field also must be set either in this array or in the objectIdField property.

From [ArcGIS JS API - FeatureLayer fields](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#fields)

Comment: Hi @cabesuon. I tried with your suggestion and I'm not getting any value to **graphic.attributes.PhysicianName**. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Can you print the parameter `graphic` of `CustomContent.creator` method and also the `attributes` property of the parameters?

Comment: Could you please refer to these console logs I've mentioned in my previous question. That's how it's printing  graphics and attributes here as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70330541/arcgis-esri-popup-template-custom-content-not-showing-graphic-attributes-ang

Comment: Hi @KalanaTebel, sorry the delay .. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70101230/issue-when-displaying-a-popup-window-in-the-esri-map/70103078#70103078) that I made a couple of weeks ago

Comment: In [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70330541/arcgis-esri-popup-template-custom-content-not-showing-graphic-attributes-ang/70397925#70397925) I post the full angular example