# ArcGIS Esri - Popup template custom content not showing graphic attributes. (Angular 11)

Tags: javascript, angular, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

I'm going to display a customContent in arcgis popup template in Angular 11 application. But the value of **graphic.attributes** is not coming to the innerText. In console log I can see the graphic objects are coming as expected. But it's showing **undefined** for **grahpic.attributes** Can anyone help with to solve this issue?

```
            new CustomContent({
    outFields: ["*"],
    creator: (eventOrGraphic) => {
        const graphic = eventOrGraphic instanceof Graphic ? eventOrGraphic : eventOrGraphic.graphic;
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = graphic.attributes.url;
        a.target = "_blank";
        a.innerText = graphic.attributes.url;
        return a;
    }
})
```

Console.log(eventOrGraphic)

```
graphic: p
destroy: ƒ value()
initialize: ƒ value()
uid: 1474
__accessor__: g {host: p, properties: Map(8), ctorArgs: null, destroyed: false, lifecycle: 2, …}
attributes: (...)    
geometry: (...)
isAggregate: (...)
layer: (...)
popupTemplate: (...)
sourceLayer: (...)
symbol: (...)
visible: (...)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Console.log(graphic.attributes) -  **undefined**

*arcgis-js-api(4.2.1)*

Comment: Hi @KalanaTebel, I think this is probably related to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312903/arcgis-js-api-custom-content-in-popup-template-is-display-nothing-angular-11/70330914#70330914) .. I answer there let me know if fix your problem

Comment: Hi @cabesuon. I just updated the code there and can you please check it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312903/arcgis-js-api-custom-content-in-popup-template-is-display-nothing-angular-11

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70101230/issue-when-displaying-a-popup-window-in-the-esri-map/70103078#70103078), and try this line just to double check that the parameter is actually a `Graphic` or an event, let me know the result

Comment: Hi @cabesuon. I've updated the code but not working. I'm getting this error from this line .         _const graphic = eventOrGraphic instanceof Graphic ? eventOrGraphic : eventOrGraphic.graphic;_
**Property 'graphic' does not exist on type 'never'.**

Comment: Is `eventOrGraphic` defined?

Comment: Hi @Carson. Yeah, Its defined

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that the parameter of `CustomContent` `creator` function is of the form `{graphic: Graphic}`.

The `never` error is because not type was assigned, so you can assign `any` to actually avoid it. I am not exactly sure of the correct type.

This is the key part of the example,

```
new CustomContent({
  outFields: ["*"],
  creator: (event: any) => {
    console.log(event.graphic);
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = event.graphic.attributes.url;
    a.target = "_blank";
    a.innerText = event.graphic.attributes.url;
    console.log(event.graphic.attributes.url);
    return a;
  }
})
```

This is the whole example,

**app.component.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  OnDestroy,
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';

import ArcGISMap from '@arcgis/core/Map';
import Graphic from '@arcgis/core/Graphic';
import MapView from '@arcgis/core/views/MapView';
import FeatureLayer from '@arcgis/core/layers/FeatureLayer';
import Collection from "@arcgis/core/core/Collection";
import CustomContent from '@arcgis/core/popup/content/CustomContent';
import PopupTemplate from '@arcgis/core/PopupTemplate';
import SimpleRenderer from "@arcgis/core/renderers/SimpleRenderer";
import TextSymbol from "@arcgis/core/symbols/TextSymbol";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('mapViewNode', { static: true }) private mapViewEl!: ElementRef;
  public view: any = null;

  initializeMap(): Promise<any> {
    const container = this.mapViewEl.nativeElement;

    const map = new ArcGISMap({
      basemap: "streets-navigation-vector"
    });

    const view = new MapView({
      container: container,
      map: map,
      zoom: 12,
      center: { type: 'point', x: -117.1490, y: 32.7353 }
    });

    const popupTemplate = new PopupTemplate({
      title: "{name}",
      content: [
        {
          type: "fields",
          fieldInfos: [
            {
              fieldName: "addrs",
              label: "Address"
            },
            {
              fieldName: "lat",
              label: "Latitude",
              format: {
                places: 2
              }
            },
            {
              fieldName: "lon",
              label: "Longitude",
              format: {
                places: 2
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        new CustomContent({
          outFields: ["*"],
          creator: (event: any) => {
            console.log(event.graphic);
            const a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = event.graphic.attributes.url;
            a.target = "_blank";
            a.innerText = event.graphic.attributes.url;
            console.log(event.graphic.attributes.url);
            return a;
          }
        })
      ],
      outFields: ["*"]
    });
    const data = [
      {
        lat: 32.727482,
        lon: -117.1560632,
        name: "Automotive Museum",
        addrs: "2080 Pan American Plaza, San Diego, CA 92101, United States",
        url: "http://sdautomuseum.org/"
      },
      {
        lat: 32.7136902,
        lon: -117.1763293,
        name: "USS Midway Museum",
        addrs: "910 N Harbor Dr, San Diego, CA 92101, United States",
        url: "http://www.midway.org/"
      },
      {
        lat: 32.7641112,
        lon: -117.2284536,
        name: "SeaWorld",
        addrs: "500 Sea World Dr, San Diego, CA 92109, United States",
        url: "https://seaworld.com/san-diego"
      },
      {
        lat: 32.7360032,
        lon: -117.1557741,
        name: "Zoo",
        addrs: "2920 Zoo Dr, San Diego, CA 92101, United States",
        url: "https://zoo.sandiegozoo.org/"
      }
    ];
    const layer = new FeatureLayer({
      source: new Collection(data.map((d, i) => (
        {
          geometry: {
            type: "point",
            longitude: d.lon,
            latitude: d.lat
          },
          attributes: {
            ObjectID: i,
            ...d
          }
        }
      ))),
      fields: [
        {
          name: "ObjectID",
          alias: "ObjectID",
          type: "oid"
        },
        {
          name: "name",
          alias: "Name",
          type: "string"
        },
        {
          name: "addrs",
          alias: "addrs",
          type: "string"
        },
        {
          name: "url",
          alias: "url",
          type: "string"
        },
        {
          name: "lat",
          alias: "Latitude",
          type: "double"
        },
        {
          name: "lon",
          alias: "Longitude",
          type: "double"
        },
      ],
      objectIdField: "ObjectID",
      geometryType: "point",
      renderer: new SimpleRenderer({
        symbol: new TextSymbol({
          color: "red",
          text: "\ue61d",
          font: {
            size: 30,
            family: "CalciteWebCoreIcons"
          }
        })
      }),
      popupTemplate
    });

    map.add(layer);
    this.view = view;
    return this.view.when();
  }

  ngOnInit(): any {
    this.initializeMap().then(() => {
      console.log('The map is ready.');
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.view) {
      this.view.destroy();
    }
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div #mapViewNode></div>
```

**app.component.scss**

```
@import 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.22/@arcgis/core/assets/esri/themes/light/main.css';
.esri-view {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#mapViewNode {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**styles.scss**

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It's  worked! Thank you so much :)